# Enforce a 2GB memory space for a 64-bit process

Tags: c++

Rather a theoretical question -- would anyone know how it were possible to make sure a 64-bit process is allocated no more than 2GB of continuous memory.

This came up during the porting of a 32-bit C++ application that does pointer arithmetic (bad!) and relies on subtraction results to fit on a 32-bit integer. Before fixing the pointer arithmetic to correctly handle >2GB `ptrdiff_t` values, enforcing a 2GB memory space for a process might prove to be be a quick fix.

NOTE: Targeted platforms include Solaris 10, Linux, and Windows.

Comment: What platform is this for? I can't see there being a platform-independent solution to this.

Comment: GCC or Visual C++? And if GCC, glibc right?

Comment: re platforms, solaris, linux, and windows are all targeted.

Comment: @xanatos, GCC for Linux, VC++ for Windows, Sun Studio CC for Solaris

Comment: @Nick You are quite f##### up. Three different systems :-) You can try redefining the global new/delete and hope no one is using malloc.

Comment: @xanatos -- keeping C++ portable is a joy :) Redefining allocation is definitely interesting, although might be much more painful than just fixing the pointer arithmetic.

Comment: The simplest solution is to not port it.  The only point of running 64-bit code is to take advantage of the extra address space, you'll completely defeat it by trying to restrict it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C and C++ standards do not require calls to `malloc()` or `operator new` to return memory that is contiguous with previously-returned memory, and few modern systems *would* given how virtual memory is doled out in a process.

You may be SOL on that front unless you can tell us which platform you're targetting (there may be a platform-specific solution.)

Answer (score 0):

Redefine global `new` and `delete` operators such that any allocation of chunk more then 2GB will fail...

Comment: A C++ process could use `malloc/delete`. I think the OP would have better luck replacing the "base" memory allocator of the runtime and hope the program isn't allocating directly from the OS.

Comment: `malloc()` and `free()` you mean, @xanatos. Never mix and match!